# Control high-power LED by LT3080 and PWM

Tags: pwm, led-driver, constant-current

I am a beginner in electronic circuits, so could someone check if my circuits design is correct?
What I want to achieve is as follows;

1. Light up 5 high-power LEDs ([EDC780D-1100](https://www.ushio.eu/pdf-specs/EDC780D-1100-S5.pdf))

   - Vf = 2.1 V
   - If = 800 mA
2. Control LEDs with the constant current (i.e. 800 mA)

   - To achieve exactly 800 mA, I will fine-tune the variable resistor R1
3. Reduce power consumption as much as possible

   - I want to minimize energy loss because the power source is a battery, not an electrical outlet, especially when LEDs are OFF.
4. Control LEDs dimming by Arduino PWM.

I designed the circuit based on the "Typical ApplicaTions (Low Dropout Voltage LED Driver)" of the [LT3080 document](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3080.pdf)
If I set R1=80 kΩ and R2 = 1Ω, I should be able to generate a constant current of 800 mA.
Vout will become 0.8 V, so 5 LEDs will have a room to get total 10.5 V (=2.1 x 5).
However, I am really not sure if my PWM controlling is correct.

What I thought was:

1. Shunt LEDs with Q1 so that no current flows to the LED when the PWM signal is ON.
2. However, if Q1 in on, all the current will directly goes into LT3080, so it will consume a lot of energy. Total energy consumed by LT3080 and R2 will be 800 mA x 12 V = 9.6 W.
3. So, R1 was also bypassed by Q2. If the PWM signal ON, Vset (=Vout) will become close to 0 V, thus almost no current will flow from the out pin of LT3080. Even if Vset is not completely 0 V, Q1 will ensure that no current will flow to LEDs.

Do you think this circuit design is reasonable?
Are there any pitfalls that I missed?
I am quite open to alternatives and any advice is welcome.

**edit: a screen shot of the data sheet was added**

[image]

[image]

Comment: "The LT®3080 is a 1.1A low dropout linear regulator that can be paralleled to increase output current or spread heat in surface mounted boards". You seem to want to control the input current?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a constant current (to 800 mA), but I also want to control LED dimming by  PWM. Is it not a proper method to control both current and dimming by only using LT3080? Do I need to add other components, or is there other suitable LED drivers that can achieve the constant current and the PWM control?

Comment: This device controls the current output not the input. Also, PWMing the input seems wrong. I think a better option is to find an LED driver that can do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
According to the data sheet (I edited the question and added a screenshot of the data sheet), it seems that the current going out from the "out" pin and the current flowing into the "in" pin are the same.
The only differences should be the base current of the transistor inside the LT3080, but is it that big?

Anyway, my design does not seem to be the best way to achieve my aim.
Do you have any suggestion about the LED driver which meets my aim and is easy to use (i.e., not so many external components)?

Comment: (`Total energy consumed by LT3080 and R2 will be 800 mA x 12 V = 9.6 W` About 10.5 V will be the LEDs, only 1.5 for R₂ and switch combined - .6 Watts-ish for the LT3080.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I updated the wrong hyperlink.

Comment: As for `Total energy consumed by LT3080 and R2 will be 800 mA x 12 V = 9.6 W`, I meant it under the condition where the PWM signal is ON (sorry for the bad description, I also updated the sentence a little in the question).

Comment: Since you mention plants, consider controlling brightness by adjusting the current set point rather than blinking the LEDs quickly. Besides the efficiency advantage, plants response to high intensity pulsed light may not be linear, so you are introducing additional variables into your tests.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I understand what you wrote, but blinking the LEDs quickly is what I want to do in my experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

- I found no application note suggesting LT3080 for PWM, little data on dynamic and start-up behaviour:
  Unless "lying around" (8+1 pin DD?), I'd look for a device spec'd for PWM
  (or go discrete - how exact a current is useful?
  `exactly 800 mA […] fine-tune`. Your eye won't know the difference between 720 and 800 mA (esp. at 780 nm, spec'ing mW/sr rather than cd).)
- keep an eye on power dissipation & temperature (LEDs, too)
- `The LT3080 requires an output capacitor for stability.` - read the data sheet.
  Add a capacitor close to the *SET* pin, too - data sheet seems to suggest greater 10 pF (to 100 nF, high for PWM)
- your schematic shows a small signal FET shunting 800 mA (semi-statically up to "thought 3")
- to reduce power dissipation in the LT3080, power V<sub>CONTROL</sub> from the Arduino's supply voltage rather than 12 Volts.
- to reduce off-state consumption, switch V<sub>CONTROL</sub> rather than shunting the LEDs actively
  check whether a shunt resistor (V<sub>LEDs</sub> to IN) is needed
- add a resistor from PWM to GND
- linear looks entirely reasonable

---

Alternatives include the
[ONSEMI CAT4101 LED Driver](https://www.onsemi.com/products/power-management/led-drivers/linear-led-drivers/cat4101#technical-documentation), max. 1 A Constant Current with PWM, and the
[MIC4812](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic4812.pdf)/[MIC4802](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic4802.pdf): the same chip in a 10 pin 3×3 mm 77°C/W MSOP or an 8 pin 5×4 mm 41°C/W SOIC. Eberhard Haug's [LDO page](http://led-treiber.de/html/ldo-treiber.html#MIC4802extra), paragraph *Die versteckten Eigenschaften des linearen LED-Treibers MIC4802* (The Hidden Features of the MIC4802 Linear LED Driver) got me interested in this device, retracing his conclusions.
MIC4802 pins 6&7 each sink 1/6 of the current set,
pins 5&8 1/3 each. Considering this, useful pin designations were (compare to MIC4812)
D12 pin 8
D3  pin 7
D4  pin 6 and
D56 pin 5 - or D or DD for the bunch of them.
(The pinout allows to drive 2 or 3 LEDs at the same current paralleling adjacent pins.)

I'd suggest connecting the Arduino's line regulator output to a close bypass capacitor, \$V_{in}\$(pin 1), and an about 2.2 k resistor, the other end of which goes to D(pin 5-8), driving the cathode of the 5 LED string - the anode goes to 12 Volts.
EN (pin 2) grounded with a resistor 100 k to 220 k, driven by the Arduino for shutdown and/or PWM.
\$R_{set}\$ (pin 3 to GND) to suit, I'm getting 7.5 k in parallel to a 15 k in series with a potentiometer, say 22 k(-100 k) lin, wiper collected to one end. If you want to experiment with linear control of the LED current, the data sheet shows \$V_{set}\$ from 1.33 Volts for 800 mA to 1.26 for zero:
Choose \$R_{set}\$ for minimum current above off, connect a capacitor in parallel - say, 1 μF, and a 4.7 k resistor to an Arduino PWM port. (That seems to be about 2 ms time constant. Suggesting a PWM frequency above, say, 10 kHz.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRoemR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The MIC4802 may be a better choice: one capacitor, one \$R_{SET}\$, maybe 1-2 resistors at the enable/PWM input.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very helpful comments!
Yeah, it might be better for me to look for a LED driver that is implemented with the PWM functionality.
I'll look into the details of the MIC4802 data sheet that you suggested, thank you so much!

Comment: As for your question `how accurate a current is valid?`, well, it doesn't have to be 800mA, but I want the same current each time in my repeated experiments.
As you wrote, human eyes will not be able to distinguish 780nm LED with 720 and 800 mA, but I'm trying to irradiate a biological (like plants) samples with 780 nm light and to see how they respond.

The photo-responsiveness of my samples may vary with intensity, so I want to keep the experimental conditions as consistent as possible.

Comment: It seems that I am missing a lot of things (capacitor, resistor from PWM-GND, etc.).
Also, powering the driver from the Arduino would surely reduce the energy consumption, as you wrote.
Although I'll use MIC4802 instead of LT3080, your suggestions will also help me in building a new circuit.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I missed what seems to be one serious catch to using an MIC4802 with \$V_{IN}\$ +3 to 5.5V: \$V_D \le V_{IN}\$, *absolute maximum* 6V. *I **think*** you can get by connecting "the anode" of your 5-LEDs-in-series to 12V and a 4k7 resistor from "D" to \$V_{IN}\$, but then, that's just me.

Comment: (`irradiate biological (like plants) samples with 780 nm light and to see how they respond. The photo-responsiveness of my samples may vary with intensity` put such information in your question! (see how [user1850479 commented there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/644922/control-high-power-led-by-lt3080-and-pwm/645008#comment1710720_644922).)

Comment: Another nice one: [ONSEMI CAT4101
LED Driver, max. 1 A Constant Current with PWM](https://www.onsemi.com/products/power-management/led-drivers/linear-led-drivers/cat4101#technical-documentation).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. MIC4802 requires input voltage range from 3.0 to 5.5 V. Could you explain about the circuit a little bit more? Where should the cathode of my 5-LEDs-in-series be connected, and does "D" stands for "D1" pins of MIC4802? But anyway, the use of CAT4101 seems to be more reasonable.